# How to receive a multicast-type queue message that has been created in the artemis console

Tags: activemq-artemis

1. Download Artemis2.13.0, create a multicast address test in advance, then create a multicast queue 123 on this address, use the console to send 1 message to the 123 queue
2. Use IDEA to create a springboot project, the pom file imports the following dependencies

   ```
   <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
           <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>


       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
           <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
           <version>2.13.0</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>
   ```
3. pplication.properties add configuration

   ```
   spring.artemis.mode=native
   spring.artemis.host=localhost
   spring.artemis.port=61616
   spring.artemis.user=test
   spring.artemis.password=123456

   spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true
   ```
4. Create consumer to receive messages pre-created in queue 123

   ```
   import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

   @Component
   public class Consumer{
       @JmsListener(destination="test::123")
       public void consumerMessage(String text){
           System.out.println("从queue队列收到的回复信息为:"+text);
       }

   }
   ```
5. I can't receive the message, using 2.13.0 artemis-jms-client the following error message appears

   ```
   Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'test::123' - trying to recover. Cause: AMQ229019: Queue 123 already exists on address test
   ```
6. Use IDEA to directly create a new springboot project without any modification.
7. Artemis creates a server and does not modify the broker file.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly abnormal to pre-create a multicast queue for a JMS use-case. Typically you'd simply use the name of the address as the name of the JMS topic in your application and then the broker would automatically create a queue on the address to represent the application's JMS subscription and then the application would receive any messages sent to that address. The semantics for mapping JMS concepts to the core broker implementation is discussed further in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/jms-core-mapping.html).

However, if your use-case *compels* you to pre-create the multicast queue then you can access that queue by using the fully qualified queue name (i.e. FQQN) which follows the form of `<address>::<queue>`. So in your case you'd use `test::123`, e.g.:

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "test::123")
public void receiveQueueMsg(String msg) {
    System.out.println("收到的消息为：" + msg);
}
```

FQQN syntax and functionality is discussed further in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html#fully-qualified-queue-names).

For what it's worth, I modified the [`spring-boot-integration`](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/standard/spring-boot-integration) example that ships with ActiveMQ Artemis to use the normal JMS client (i.e. not the AMQP JMS client) and to use FQQN with a multicast queue and everything worked as expected.

Comment: I have tried it, but when I start it, it will prompt that Queue 1 already exists on address test，the prompt is as follows “Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'test::123' - trying to recover. Cause: AMQ229019: Queue 1 already exists on address test”

Comment: Can you clarify why you need to pre-create the queue?

Comment: I just want to try it, because I create a queue in advance, which can be accessed through address::queue in the case of anycast, so I want to try the case of multicast, I use the SpringBoot project and import "spring-boot-starter-artemis" , "Spring-jms" and "artemis-jms-client"

Comment: I use version 2.13.0

Comment: I’m sorry for the error in the previous comment, the prompt should be “Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination'test::123'-trying to recover. Cause: AMQ229019: Queue ‘123’ already exists on address test”

Comment: I checked the artemis.log file, only the program started information, no error message, IDEA console gave me the prompt is "Queue 123 already exists on address test"

Comment: OK, I have written the steps in the question

Comment: I added the springboot application code, I used the springboot project created by IDEA, no modification

Comment: It's not clear from your question how to do this in IDEA. Please **fully document** the entire process required to reproduce the issue. I recommend you read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Okay, I have rewritten my problem description, see if this makes you clearer

Comment: Hello, can you follow the steps above to reproduce the problem